# Replace reoccurring substring with array values when there are more substrings than values

Tags: java, string, loops, stringbuilder

```
public static String updatedStr()
{
    String [] ar= {"green","red","purple","black"};

    String str="The colors are (blue), (blue), and (yellow). I prefer (orange)";

    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder ();
    int x = 0;
    int pos = 0;

    for(int i = str.indexOf('(', 0); i != -1; i = str.indexOf('(', i + 1)) {
        out.append (str.substring(pos,i)); // add the part between the last ) and the next (
        out.append (ar[x++]); // add replacement word
        pos = str.indexOf(')', i) + 1;
    }

    out.append (str.substring(pos)); // add the part after the final )
    return out.toString ();
}
```

I am able to replace whatever is inside the parentheses with elements from my string array.

Here, I achieve the output of

> "The colors are green, red, and purple. I prefer black."

Now, I am trying to implement a scenario where 
`String [] ar= {"green","red"}`.

I would like the output to be

> "The colors are green, red, and (yellow). I prefer (orange)."

As you can see, the rest of the original string remains untouched due to there not being enough values to replace them.

So far, I have tried using a while loop before the for loop to prevent an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsError`, but I am actually still getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to declare a new variable counting how many replacements have been made and stop when it has reached the array length.

```
public static String updatedStr()
{
    String [] ar= {"green","red"};
    String str="The colors are (blue), (blue), and (yellow). I prefer (orange)";

    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder ();
    int x = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    int added=0;
    for(int i = str.indexOf('(', 0); i != -1 && added<ar.length; i = str.indexOf('(', i + 1)) {
        out.append (str.substring(pos,i)); // add the part between the last ) and the next (
        out.append (ar[x++]); // add replacement word
        pos = str.indexOf(')', i) + 1;
    }
    out.append (str.substring(pos)); // add the part after the final )
    return out.toString ();
}
```